# Problem evaluating numerical value of MeijerG[] function at some parameter?

Tags: numerics, special-functions

I need to evaluate this sum:

[image]

Where x = 33.6614 and  $k,l,s$ are non-negative index of  the three sum. For example $k,l,s=0,1,2,3,...$.

Furthermore, $M$ is a positive integer that is $M=1,2,3,4...$

For the case of $s = 0,k = 0,l = 0,M = 4$, I enter my meijerG function  in this form

```
MeijerG[{{2}, {}}, {{0, 2, 3, 4 + 2}, {}}, 33.6614]
```

Mathematica said that:

```
"MeijerG[{{2},{}},{{0,2,3,6},{}},33.6614] does not exist. Arguments are not consistent"
```

Why does this happen and is there anyway to work around this ?

I myself suspect that some there might be some condition regarding the variable $l,s,k,M$ but it just some gut feeling

Thank you very much !

P/S:

For more information, the big meijerG function that I am trying to evaluate come from the evaluation of this integral

[image]

```
Integrate[(-z/\[Gamma])^S* (1/z)^L *Exp[-(a + c)/(z*\[CapitalOmega])]*
  MeijerG[{{1}, {}}, {{k + 1, k + 2, k + M + 1}, {}}, z*e], {z, 
  0, \[Infinity]}, 
 Assumptions -> 
  Element[{a, c, \[CapitalOmega], \[Gamma], e}, PositiveReals]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do

```
l = 0.; k = 0; m = 1; Plot[MeijerG[{{2 - l + s}, {}}, 
{{0, 2 + k - l + s, 3 + k - l + s, 2 + k - l + m + s}, {}}, 30], {s, -0.1, 0.1}]
```

you see that at l=0 && s=0 the function is not defined. There may be other places in parameter space where this is also the case (see Wikipedia entry for MeijerG).